# Checking whether there is a logger set to DEBUG in Log4J

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have code which is called so many times which even calling logger.isDebugEnabled() cost too much.
I can store the isDebugEnabled() value into a static variable on the class but then I loose the option to enable debug during server run.
Today all my calls to Log4J are done by custom wrappers.
I want to implement a solution that if no logger is set to debug I will be able to return ASAP by checking some global boolean variable and only if one or more loggers are set to debug the wrappers will forward the call to Log4J.

Is there a way to ask Log4J configuration if there is one or more loggers set to debug?
That way I can check it every 5 seconds and will switch on / off a global boolean which will be used by my wrappers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having performance issues with Log4j I recommend taking a look at [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).

If you need to stick with log4j you can do one of the following.
The following code will check the logging level of the root logger. This is likely all you need.

```
Level level = LogManager.getRootLogger().getLevel();
if(level == Level.DEBUG)
    System.out.println("DEBUG");
```

In the event that you actually do want to check every logger, you can do this.

```
 for (Enumeration<Logger> en = LogManager.getCurrentLoggers(); en.hasMoreElements();)
   System.out.println(en.nextElement().isDebugEnabled());
```

For completeness you can change the root logging level with the following.

```
LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

Comment: If the debug was enabled on a specific class, will the LogManager.getRootLogger().getLevel() return true? @Zig158

Comment: No. I just tested it with Logj4 1.2.17.

If you are doing logging from a tight look just check isDebugEnabled() at the beginning of the loop.